# How to Flush Crawl Database Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have problem with Crawl Database which is now around 379 GB (.ldf file).
We have total of 210 GB in content database but this is too much for logs.

Recovery is set to Full because Always ON and I did not enable Auto Shrink because I am not sure it is smart to do?

[image]

What do you suggest on this?
Is this size normal?
I found different things for SP 2010 but nothing in 2013.

Thanks

Comment: I think crawl database is for SharePoint search and not logs. Also, the size of the crawl database depends on what all you have in content sources? You can shrink the databases periodically(say weekly/monthly) depending on how frequently your database changes size.

Comment: Shrinking is almost never the right answer, unless you have >50% free space in the database.

Comment: Please tell us which part of the databases consumes most of the disk-space. Is it the data file (.mdf) or the logfile (.ldf). The correct solution heavily depends on that. PS: AUTO-Shrink is never an answer.

Comment: I have updated questions. It is logfile

Comment: try to run a full backup of the Crawl Database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had to set the Recovery-Model of the Database to "FULL" to successfully implement AlwaysOn. RecoveryModel FULL also means, that the TransactionLog never gets cleared unless you do a TransactionLog-Backup (aka. incremental backup).

- Configure your existing backup to also schedule a TransactionLog-Backup / incremental Backup. A full-backup of your database is not sufficient!
- After your fist TransactionLog-Backup completed, immediately(!) shrink the logfile once to a appropriate size. Execute the following commands in SQL-Server Management Studio:

> USE [DatabaseName];
>
> DBCC SHRINKFILE (DatabaseName_Search_Crawlstore_log, 4096);

- This should shrink your LDF-File to a size of 4 Gigabytes. Don't hassle if you do not hit the exact size of 4 GB. There are [several reasons for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779153/why-cant-i-shrink-a-transaction-log-file-even-after-backup).

Comment: You should also check your other databases for that problem. They might not grow that fast as the CrawlStore-DB, but might face the same issue and waste tons of disk space.